# Using weight for Random forest of sklearn

Tags: python, numpy, import, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to use weight for RandomForestClassifier of sklearn.
In fact, I have an imbalanced dataset. class 1 with 600, class2 90, class3 60 and class4 96 sample data!!!

I want to use weight to make the dataset balanced. This is my code that generated an error.

```
cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs =5,{1:1,2:3,3:3,4:3})
cfr.fit(XTrain,yTrain)
predictedTest=cfr.predict(XTest)
```

This is the error.

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

And also I have problem to choose a number as a weight. Could you please guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two arguments of

```
cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs =5,{1:1,2:3,3:3,4:3})
```

are keyword arguments, where you are specifying the arguments out of order by using the syntax "arg=value".  As you move from left to right in the argument list, once you start giving keyword arguments, you cannot stop.  Every argument afterward has to be a keyword argument.  EDIT: Since all the arguments to RandomForestClassifier have keywords, you just need to add the keyword for the last one.

```
cfr = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100,n_jobs=5,class_weight={1:1,2:3,3:3,4:3})
```